# How to execute a function only once a Promise is done?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, promise, stripe-payments

**QUESTION:**

I would like to make changes to my database only if the charge was successful.

That is currently not the case. `ARef.push(object)` is triggered before the charge is done processing.

What is wrong in my synatx ?

---

**CODE:**

```
router.post("/", (req, res) => {

    var amount = req.body.amount;
    var object;
    var ARef = admin.database().ref("ref");
    var ARefList;
    amount = amount * 100; 

    var object = {
        amount: amount,
        email: email,
        inversedTimeStamp: now
    }

    stripe.customers.create({
        email: req.body.stripeEmail,
        source: req.body.stripeToken
    })
    .then(customer =>
        stripe.charges.create({
            amount: amount,
            description: "desc",
            currency: "usd",
            customer: customer.id
        })
    )
    .then(charge => 
        ARef.transaction(function(dbAmount){  
            if (!dbAmount) { 
              dbAmount = 0; 
            } 
            dbAmount = dbAmount + amount/100; 
            return dbAmount; 
        })
    )
    .then(
        // this happens regardless of the success of the charge
        ARef.push(object)
        //
    )
    .then (
        ARefList.push(object)
    )
    .then(
        res.render("received",{amount:amount/100})
    );
});
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Sorry for that. I removed that part of the code because it's not relevant here :/ My issue is that ARef.push(object) is triggered before the stripe  promise has finished processing the charge.

Comment: Which code does "process the charge"? That  `stripe.charges.create` thing? Does it return a promise?

Comment: .then will be executed whether or not the promise is a fail or a success. Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: @TheProgrammer: Okay. It looked incorrect, though, FWIW.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I think you must be right : I am just trying to fix my code one piece at a time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In these lines:

```
.then(
    // this happens regardless of the success of the charge
    ARef.push(object)
    //
)
.then (
    ARefList.push(object)
)
```

you're **calling** `ARef.push` and passing its return value into `then`. So that happens when the chain is established, not later when it's resolved/rejected.

To call them as *part* of the resolution chain, pass in a function, not the result of `push`:

```
.then(() => {
    ARef.push(object)
    //
})
.then (() => {
    ARefList.push(object)
})
```

Similarly, this looks suspect:

```
.then(charge => 
    ARef.transaction(function(dbAmount){  
        if (!dbAmount) { 
          dbAmount = 0; 
        } 
        dbAmount = dbAmount + amount/100; 
        return dbAmount; 
    })
)
```

`ARef.transaction` doesn't look like it returns a promise, but it does accept a callback suggesting that it's asynchronous (though that's not the only reason for accepting a callback). If it doesn't provide a promise, you may have to create your own:

```
.then(charge =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        ARef.transaction(function(dbAmount){
            // How do you know whether this failed? However it is,
            // ensure you call `reject` when it does.
            if (!dbAmount) { 
              dbAmount = 0; 
            } 
            dbAmount = dbAmount + amount/100; 
            resolve(dbAmount); // <== Resolve with whatever value should
                               // go to the next link in the chain
        })
    })
)
```

---

Back to the first part:

It's not clear where `object` is meant to come from, though. If it is the resolution value that the first `then` callback above will receive, then:

```
.then(object => {
    ARef.push(object)
    //
})
.then (() => {
    ARefList.push(object)
})
```

Similarly, that `then` handler will need to return something if the next `then` handler is meant to receive it:

```
.then(object => {
    ARef.push(object)
    return object;
})
.then (object => {
    ARefList.push(object)
})
```

That, or combine those two handlers:

```
.then(object => {
    ARef.push(object)
    ARefList.push(object)
})
```

Comment: sorry about the "object" confusion, I had forgotten that var, it's not a return value

Comment: @TheProgrammer: No worries. I added a note above about `ARef.transaction`. HTH.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you wanted to do this - .then needs a callback fn:

```
() => aRef.push(object)
```